# Custom post type functions.php if statement on action

Tags: wordpress, function, action, custom-post-type

I am using developing a child theme for Woothemes' Canvas.

I am trying to use functions.php in the child theme to only use actions on my custom post type.

This code doesn't seem to be working:

```
 add_action( 'woo_post_inside_after', 'my_geo_mashup' );
function my_geo_mashup() {
       echo GeoMashup::map();
    if ($post->post_type == 'listings') {
        //My function
       }
}

add_action( 'woo_post_inside_before', 'listings_nivo' );
function listings_nivo() {
echo do_shortcode('[nivo source="current-post" ]');
 if ($post->post_type == 'listings') {
        //My function
       }
}
```

So, I'm unsure how to get the above to work properly and only show these items on the custom post type, or only for the custom post type template single-listings.php (as I only want the map and slider to show on the actual post, not on the blog page (archive.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than making the entire $post object global, you can just make $post_type global instead. Ex below.

I'm not exactly sure where that function is being loaded, but make sure you hook somewhere within the post.  If the action is before, as far as I know and from experience, the post variable will be null.

Just as a test, try running the action in wp_footer Ex. add_action( 'wp_footer', 'listings_nivo' );
See if that yeilds any results.

if echoing var_dump($post) is still null, well, not sure where to go from there.

So you can try running the below, then run the action in the appropriate place if it works:

```
function listings_nivo() {
    echo do_shortcode('[nivo source="current-post" ]');
    global $post_type;
        // Diagnostic purposes
    echo var_dump($post_type);
    if ($post_type == 'listings') {
            //My function
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'listings_nivo' );
```

Check your error log or turn wp_debug to true in your wp-config.php file if nothing else to see if anything else is going on.

Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

Inside your function, try adding `global $post;`. Then to see what you are getting with `$post->post_type` echo it out to the screen. As long as this gives you "listings", your code should work. If not, there's probably another issue at play.

Comment: Unfortunately, I didn't find any other issue. For now, I've just hardcoded the call into the custom post type template, which works great, I was just trying to keep it all within functions.php

Comment: So, making the post variable global didn't work? If that is the case there are other options. You just need to access the post information and there are a few ways to do that.

Comment: This really comes down to how to get the post ID. Once you have it, you can do something like `$post = get_post($post_ID); $page_type = $post->page_type`. Inside the loop, you can get the ID with `global $post; $post_ID = $post->ID;`. On a page, outside the loop, you can get the ID with `$post_ID = $post->ID`. In other contexts, you may get the ID for the $_POST array. The reason your original code does not work is because the $post variable will not be available to you inside a function without `global $post`. Depending on the context of the use of the function, that may not even work.